# Why is the solution to the differential equation $v'(t)=\Lambda v,$ $ v(t)=\exp(\Lambda t)v(0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $\frac{dv}{dt}=\Lambda v$

We get the solution $v(t)=e^{\Lambda t}v(0)$

In this case $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalue constants.

The main question I have is: when is a solution to differential equation an exponential times the starting condition at t=0?

The equation comes from this lecture: https://youtu.be/IZqwi0wJovM?t=1903

Comment: Maybe you have a typo. The equation should be $\frac{dv}{dt}=\Lambda v$ and $\Lambda$ a square matrix.

Comment: You're right $\Lambda$ is a square diagonal matrix. Updated my question. Sorry still trying to get to grips on everything happening here.

Comment: Read the comment of xpaul thoroughly.

Comment: In the Youtube notes it says start with dv/dt = Lambda v.  This says the derivative of a (vector) variable is a constant times the variable.  From differential equations, you know the solution is an exponential function (multiplied by the initial condition).

How do you know?

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{\Lambda t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\Lambda t)^k}{k!}$$

With $\displaystyle v(t) = e^{\Lambda t} v(0),$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{dv(t)}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\Lambda t)^k}{k!} v(0)\\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dt} \frac{(\Lambda t)^k}{k!} v(0)\\
&= \Lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{k(\Lambda t)^{k-1}}{k!} v(0)\\
&= \Lambda \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{\Lambda^{k-1}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} v(0)\\
&=  \Lambda \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{(\Lambda t)^{k}}{k!} v(0)\\
&= \Lambda e^{\Lambda t} v(0)\\
&= \Lambda v(t).
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\displaystyle v(t) = e^{\Lambda t} v(0)$ satistifies the differential equation and initial condition, it is the solution.

The solution is unique:

Let $w(t)$ be another solution.  Then, $p(t)=v(t)-w(t)$ would satisfy the differential equation $p^\prime = \Lambda p$ with initial conditions $p(0)=0$.  Thus $p^\prime(0)=\Lambda p(0)=0$ and repeatedly differentiating the equation shows that all derivatives of $p(t)$ are zero at $t=0$.  Thus the McLauren series for $p$ has terms all zero, so $p(t)$ is identically zero and $w(t)=v(t).$